# Robo3T Linux Migrating from local

Tags: mongodb, mlab, robo3t

I am trying to copy my local database to  MLab for production.I have seen a copy database [tutorial](https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/copy-mongodb-collection/) on robo3t's page but there is no option in my linux robo3t. I also tried `mongodump` but I don't have a static IP and I couldn't think of any other option

Comment: Could you elaborate what's the problem to the ones who haven't seen the tutorial and don't know what's your linux app is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but you can not do that with Robo3t on Linux